# how to check for a string in url using selenium ide

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, integration-testing, selenium-ide

In my scenario when I click on a tab in my website it leads to ajax service call and url contains few parameters regarding the data that is loaded after tab click. Data is in the form of horizontal tiles one below the other and on one page 4 tiles are loaded. For this in url we have load=4. My requirement is to check whether load=4 is present in url or not using one or more selenium IDE commands. Please suggest!

Comment: In Javascript it could be `window.location.href.indexOf("load=4")`. If the return value is >0 it contains the given String

Comment: You can check the url if it's attached to the tab in an href. I think you'll be out of luck if you want to look at it AFTER the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
verifyEval | window.location.href.indexOf("load=4") == -1 | true
```

Will fail if there is load=4 in your url

```
verifyEval | window.location.href.indexOf("load=4") == -1 | false
```

Will pass if there is load=4 in your url